# Connect Esper with PostgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, esper

(1) I need to connect Esper database adapter to my project. Im using [this](http://www.espertech.com/esper/release-5.5.0/esperio-reference/html/adapter_db.html)
as guide, but I do not know where to locate the configuration file because im getting this error: `Cannot locate configuration information for database 'db1'`

This is what i have

```
public class Esper {


public void iniciar() {
    EPServiceProvider epService = EPServiceProviderManager.getDefaultProvider();

    ConfigurationDBAdapter adapterConfig = new ConfigurationDBAdapter();
    ConfigurationDBRef configDB = new ConfigurationDBRef();
    configDB.setDriverManagerConnection("org.postgresql.Driver",
            "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db_name", 
            "user", 
            "pass");
    adapterConfig.getJdbcConnections().put("db1", configDB);

    EsperIODBAdapter dbAdapter = new EsperIODBAdapter(adapterConfig, "engineURI");
    dbAdapter.start();

    String expression = "select * from pattern[every timer :interval(10)], sql:db1 ['select mosquitoId from registros where velocidad > 50']";
    EPStatement stmt = epService.getEPAdministrator().createEPL(expression);
    Mylistener listener = new Mylistener();
    stmt.addListener(listener);
}
}
```

(2) What i need to do is get data from table `Registros` and if `velocidad > 50` use printLn(), i dont understand what is `pattern` in the example.

Comment: maybe instead of `sql:db1` you have to use `sql:db_name` ?

Comment: @YCF_L nop, I already tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of "EPServiceProviderManager.getDefaultProvider();" you would want to use "EPServiceProviderManager.getDefaultProvider(configuration);".

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
ConfigurationDBRef configDB = new ConfigurationDBRef();
configDB.setDriverManagerConnection(....);
configuration.addDatabaseReference("MyDB", configDB);
EPServiceProvider epService = EPServiceProviderManager.getDefaultProvider(configuration);
```